# How to repair corrupted java class in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While i was coding java application in intellij my laptop shutdown suddenly when i opened my laptop and opened my project to continue coding ,i found java class which contains 21000 lines of code has damaged and when i opened it in notepad++ it's shown as alot of nulls as shown in the image below , so i want to know how to retrieve this code ?[image]

Comment: Unless you took a backup somewhere. THere is nothing much that can be done. Good practices are having a configuration management system and not having classes that run in 21k lines.

Comment: In eclipse there is a local history you can access. Maybe intellij has something similar

Comment: Use a VCS next time!

Answer (score 2):

Open your project in IDEA, right-click on class, Local history -> Show history. Here you can revert your code to latest snapshot.

PS: class with 21000 lines of code - it's something... crazy!

Comment: there's no any thing in local history but at the above of local history screen there's a text told contents are identical which in yellow bar